# Best way to create a process step diagram in Excel

Tags: excel, vba

Consider below set up:

[image]

Whenever you enter value under **Time**, it will be mapped on the right side under **Process Time** using the correct line legend depending on what column you enter your input.

I know my question would be a bit off topic or too broad, but I was hoping that someone may share their idea on how to accomplish the same other than VBA. I am currently doing this using `Change_Event` but this may be hard to maintain as *steps* may vary as well as the *time intervals*.

I also come-up with another solution using *Conditional Formatting* (same as the available template that Excel 2013 offers - *Project Planner*) but my customer wish to (as much as possible) preserve the legends.

So before I go on optimizing the current routine I've written, I want to consult on the communities opinion if I am on the right track on using *brute force* VBA (automating inserting and deleting lines) or if there is a simpler way. I just felt that maybe I am overdoing things (especially on the freeform line)

Comment: VBA is the only thing that comes to mind to manage this kind of an effort in Excel. I feel you are on the right track with VBA

Comment: I'm thinking about a Pivot table based on a data table. You can give a number format for assigned character code e.g. *[=1]"A";[=2]"B"* Refreshing wouldn't come automatically and it would look less clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had already a solution for this without VBA. But of course the legend symbols must be character glyphs. So they are not as flexible as you need. But maybe you get stimuli how programming this in VBA from this.

[image]

There is only one Formula in `F4` copied cross down.

```
=IF(AND(SUM($B$3:$E3)<F$2,SUM($B$4:$E4)>=F$2),REPT(CHOOSE(MATCH(0,$B4:$E4,-1),"—","-","~","═"),4),"")
```

Row 3 must be empty. All times must be multiples of 10. And there is only one kind of process possible in each step. The cells `F4:O10` must be formatted with a proportional font.

Comment: Have shortcomings but I still say it is clever.